# Make Chrome search bar prefer visited sites over less relevant "suggested" sites

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar, omnibox

How can I make Chrome prefer my history over what seems to be paid results?

Not now nor have I **ever** been interested in General Motors.

I just want to confidently type "gm", hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and go to gmail.

I've tried:

- Cleared my browser history of all non-gmail entries of "gm"
- Adding GMAIL as a bookmark
- It's even in my top sites on a new tab

To note, I have plenty of other frequented sites which get suggested first no problem.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you define gmail as bookmark ?

Comment: @harrymc I did, doesn't work. Sorry, I forgot to add that to my question.

Comment: Of course it does work. Just position to it and press Ctrl+D.

Comment: @harrymc I'm gonna assume you were pedantically facetious on purpose. See my updated post and screenshot =)

Comment: In `chrome://flags/` there are about 40 poorly documented omnibox options,
but perhaps one of them does something useful. If you dont find one, in
`chrome://settings/searchEngines` there is "Site search" where there is a
shortcut `@bookmarks` for searching within bookmarks. Edit this to just "b"
then you can enter in omnibox: "b gm".

Comment: In `chrome://omnibox/` you get an omnibox which shows you the list of things to list, but also **why** it chose them. It might provide a clue.

Comment: @meuh That's amazing! I think I figured out the issue but am unsure of how to fix it =/ See my self-answer below.

Comment: You might get less junk from google if you go to Settings -> Sync and Google
services, i.e.`chrome://settings/syncSetup`, and turn off "Improve search
suggestions".  Alternatively, set a different default search engine, like duckduckgo.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [meuh](https://superuser.com/users/458747/meuh)'s [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1799907/make-chrome-search-bar-prefer-visited-sites-over-less-relevant-suggested-sites?noredirect=1#comment2820877_1799907) to use `chrome://omnibox/` I was able to uncover this:

[image]

Hovering the `df` column reveals the following description:

> Can be Default
> A green checkmark indicates that the result can be the default match (i.e., can be the match that pressing enter in the omnibox navigates to).

If I am understanding the screen properly, then even though there is a high Relevance score, 1399, the result is not allowed to be present when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>